# Existence of a Non-Measurable Function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to answer if there exists a non-measurable function f from R to R such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is measurable for any y in R.

My thoughts:

I believe that we can find such a function since we can find a sequence of point wisely convergent simple functions $f_n$ but not uniformly convergent functions. I am thinking of the sequence of functions $f_n$ = ${\frac{x}{n}}$, which converge point wise to $f$ = $0$ for x between 0 and 1. The function $f$ has a pre-image which is measurable (either singletons or empty set), but yet is not measurable since $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to f. (Note: I am using the definition of measurability of a function where a function is measurable iff it can be represented as the limit of uniformly convergent sequences of simple functions.) However, I am not 100% sure of my example. Can someone please let me know if I am in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Your sequence $f_n$ converges pointwise to zero for _any_ $x$. Also, your function $f$ (which is not the correct limit) is measurable.

Answer (score 2):

Choose a non-measurable set $E\subseteq(0,1)$ and define $f(x)=x$ for $x\in E$ and $f(x)=-x$ for $x\in(0,1)-E$ and $f(x)=2$ for otherwise.

Comment: Very nice! Simple but compelling.

Comment: Ok, but since you chose your set to be non-measurable, wouldn't taking the pre-image make it a non-measurable set as well for x in E? Sorry, I am just not seeing how defining f like you did solves the problem.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. But the fact is that, $f^{-1}((0,1))=E$, if $f$ were measurable, then so is $f^{-1}((0,1))$, but the construction is that it isn't.

Comment: Sorry, I was not thinking clearly. Now that I drew myself a nice picture I see things and am convinced. Thanks.